# Validating User form Data using excel vba

Tags: forms, excel, validation, vba

I am writing code to fill a cell through user form. I need to check if data is between 0 and 1 and prompt user to enter correct data.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
wt = TextBox1.Value
If wt >= 0 And wt <= 1 Then

        Range("Wt!B2").Value = wt

 Else

         MsgBox "Enter a number between 0 and 1"

 End If
 End Sub
```

`
The code works, but the irritating problem is even before I finish entering a number, the alert pops. How can I avoid it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The modified code is given below.

```
Dim flag As Integer
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

  If flag = 1 Then

      MsgBox "Enter values between 0 and 1"
  Else
    Range("Wt!B2").Value = TextBox1.Value
    Unload Me
  End If
End Sub


Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
 Dim wt As Double, new_value As Double
 TextBox1.SetFocus
If IsNumeric(TextBox1.Value) Then
    new_value = CDbl(TextBox1.Value)
Else
    new_value = 0
End If
wt = new_value
DataValidate (wt)
End Sub

Sub DataValidate(wt)

If wt >= 0 And wt <= 1 Then

   'do nothing

Else
   flag = 1

End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Many options.  It comes down to your personal preference.

Are you annoyed that you get an error immediately after pressing an invalid key?
I consider that good behavior.

Are you annoyed that that you get an error when the text box is cleared?
Try

```
If wt >= 0 And wt <= 1 Or wt = "" Then
if wt <> "" then Range("Wt!B2").Value = wt
```

Personally, I don't consider a text box an appropriate control for essentially a binary choice.  Have  you considered a toggle button?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I had already modified my code and used a button. Basically the problem was due to incorrect formatting as I had declared wt as double and was reading from a text-box.I am posting my modified code below. It works fine. I also extended it to cover a range of cells.

Comment: Glad to see it.  I really missed the mark with 0><1  I use integers almost exclusively and didn't even consider the world that exists between them.  An observation on your flag.  If you declare it as a boolean and give it a helpful name then you can make plain english statements like : If UserQuit Then Exit    or   If not HeadersMatch Then ErrorFound = true

Comment: Thank You @Profoundly Oblivious. I will try that.